# Selenium textbox NULL text

Tags: c#, selenium

I think I have a bit of bad coding that I'm trying to write a Selenium test against.  The textbox in question has a default value of "30" that is set all the time (server-side asp.net).  However, during execution of the screen the javascript populates the text like so:

```
document.getElementById("txtEQ").value = eqVal;
```

The following is the output of the textbox after the calulation (javascript) has been run:

[image]

However, the source still shows a value="30"

[image: TextBox source]

In my selenium code I have tried just getting the text,but it always returns null.

```
 Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id(txtEQ)).Text
```

When I try to get the value, I always get 30.

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id(txtEQ)).GetAttribute("Value")
```

I've also tried this (and many other variations):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Instance;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('txtEQ').text;").ToString();
```

This returns NULL all the time.

I'm not quiet sure what I can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run this command:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Instance;
js.ExecuteScript("$(\"#txtEQ\").val(\"25\").change();")
```

Trigger a change event on the element might solve this problem for you.

Then do:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("txtEQ")).GetAttribute("Value")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  The value remained at 30.